# Need to Identify unknown components D53, CT7 and 22X

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, identification

Please help me to find unknown components[image: PIC18F2550 micro controller]

Comment: Ic5 must be a USB TVS. Just take anything that is rated for usb2. Look for littlefuse or bourns.

Comment: Thanks Gregory. But what about D53 and CT7>

Comment: No idea. Need to google, it's not convenient from cell phone. I bet, diode can be anything, just be sure reverse voltage is about 40v or more. The last one may be a sensor or an eeprom. Don't know.

Comment: IC5 looks to be a USB EMI and ESD filter. It is similar to the part in the link below, but the pinout is different. http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/STF202-22T1-D.PDF

Comment: Is there anybody can help?

Comment: IC4 may be a Texas Instruments DAC5311 http://www.ti.com/product/DAC5311

Comment: Dear Bruce, Thank you a lot. It solve my major problem. Any idea about Unknown diode?

Comment: You should really add more info about the circuit. Where is it from? What is it used for? It's like you're going to a biologist with a plat cell, ask him what the use of that cell is, but neglect to tell that scientist what kind of organism you've got that from!

Answer (score 1):

IC5 is definitely a USB TVS diode array. TI.com has some products of that category, and app notes that explain them.

Ct7 is a a Diode in reverse against ground; that screams "constant voltage or voltage limiting" all over, especially if it's indeed a Zener diode. You should be able to measure the breakdown voltage if it is <5V within the circuit easily - neither the inputs of the LM358 nor the PIC are overly sensitive, especially when the rest of the circuit is unpowered.

Seing that IC4 has three connections to the MCU, it's probably something digital. But: the only pin not going to the MCU goes to In+ of the LM358's first opamp. Seeing that the opamp is configured in some kind of low-pass filter (capacitance in feedback) configuration, I "clearly" see a DAC with an anti-imaging output filter.

Wild guess: these inputs get sampled by the ADC of the PIC, and the DAC is used to bias/adjust the signal in some way.